# How do I access instance data from a method in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, edit

So I am trying to create a public method that can be called by class a so that it edits a data item in class b.

```
class aClass():
    def __init__(self):
        aVariable = 1

class aNotherClass():
    def aMethod(self):
        aFunction(5)

def aFunction(aNumber):
    instance1.aVariable = aNumber

instance1 = aClass()
instance2 = aNotherClass()
instance2.aMethod
```

However, when I call instance1 in aFunction, python tells me it isn't defined. If I want to change aVariable in aClass, what should aFunction() say?

Comment: Why don't you make `instance1` a *parameter* to `aFunction`? Could you provide a less... abstract example?

Comment: You have no `self` parameters on your methods, so using `aClass()` alone is already going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may forget the `self` when you define a class method.

refer to: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

```
class aClass():
    def __init__(self):
        aVariable = 1

class aNotherClass():
    def aMethod(self):
        aFunction(5)

def aFunction(aNumber):
    instance1.aVariable = aNumber

instance1 = aClass()
instance2 = aNotherClass()
instance2.aMethod()
```

Comment: Sorry, I just typed this out too fast. I did include the self parameter in my actual code. I fixed that now.